# Disadvantages of multi-level caching in system design

Tags: system-design

I am working on an application which has multi-level caching. So its guavacache->redis->database to fetch anything without directly going to database. But I read somewhere that having multi level caching might always not be a good idea. I am totally confused now. As in my understanding this will decrease the throughput on the database. Can someone help me in understanding this?

PS: I am new to this platform, so please excuse for this vague way of asking question.

Comment: Take a look at https://www.bufferbloat.net/projects/ for a good primer.

Comment: While writing to DB, an application needs to invalidate the data in two caches instead of one.